# replace string with a random character from a selection

Tags: r, string, random, replace

How can you take the string and replace every instance of `"."`, `","`, `" "` (i.e. dot, comma or space) with one random character selected from `c('|', ':', '@', '*')`?

Say I have a string like this

```
 Aenean ut odio dignissim augue rutrum faucibus. Fusce posuere, tellus eget viverra mattis, erat tellus porta mi, at facilisis sem nibh non urna. Phasellus quis turpis quis mauris suscipit vulputate. Sed interdum lacus non velit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae;
```

To get one random character, we can treat the characters as a vector then use `sample` function to select one out. I assume first I need to search for dot, comma or space, then use `gsub` function to replace all these?

Comment: `gsub('[., ]', sample(c('|',':','@','*'), 1), s)` where `s` is the string.

Comment: Do you want the (dot, comma or space) always replaced with the same character?

Comment: @thelatemail no. just anyone from the c(‘|’,‘:’,‘@’,’*')

Comment: @alistaire it replaces with one random character selected from the character vectors. thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your clarification, try this one:

```
x <- c("this, is nice.", "nice, this is.")
gr <- gregexpr("[., ]", x)
regmatches(x,gr) <- lapply(lengths(gr), sample, x=c('|',':','@','*'))
x
#[1] "this|*is@nice:" "nice@|this*is:"
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another option with `chartr`

```
pat <- paste(sample(c('|', ';', '@', '*'), 3), collapse="")
chartr('., ', pat, x)
#[1] "this|*is*nice;" "nice|*this*is;"
```

#### data

```
x <- c("this, is nice.", "nice, this is.")
```

Comment: Marginally different results from mine in that it will match each original character to the same new character, but I do like `chartr` as I think it is outsourced to C code.

Comment: @thelatemail You are right that it will match the same character.  While reading the OP's question, it was not very clear

Comment: @akrun right. thanks for the effort! that's another good way to approach!